# Output coming from virtual class

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a C++ test next Tuesday about virtual types, inheritance, etc. My issue is that I have a strange output coming from my code, and I don't have a clue where is it coming from:

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using std::cout; using std::endl;

template<int id> class B{
    int* p;

public:
    B(): p{new int}{
        cout << typeid(*this).name() << "::" << typeid(*this).name() << "()" << endl;
    }

    B(const B& b): p{new int{*(b.p)}}{
        cout << typeid(*this).name() << "::" << typeid(*this).name() << "(const " << typeid(*this).name() << "&)" << endl;
    }

    virtual ~B(){
        delete p;
        cout << typeid(*this).name() << "::~" << typeid(*this).name() << "()" << endl;
    }
};

class D: public B<0>{

public:
    D(){
        cout << "D::D()" << endl;
    }

    D(const D& d): B<0>{static_cast<const B&>(d)}, b1{d.b1}, b2{d.b2}{
        cout << "D::D(const D&)" << endl;
    }

    ~D(){
        cout << "D::~D()" << endl;
    }

private:

    B<1> b1;
    B<2> b2;
};

int main()
{
    B<0>& b{*new D};
    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;
    D d{dynamic_cast<D&>(b)};
    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;
    delete &b;
    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;
}
```

**Output:**

```
1BILi0EE::1BILi0EE()
1BILi1EE::1BILi1EE()
1BILi2EE::1BILi2EE()
D::D()
-----------------------------
1BILi0EE::1BILi0EE(const 1BILi0EE&)
1BILi1EE::1BILi1EE(const 1BILi1EE&)
1BILi2EE::1BILi2EE(const 1BILi2EE&)
D::D(const D&)
-----------------------------
D::~D()
1BILi2EE::~1BILi2EE()
1BILi1EE::~1BILi1EE()
1BILi0EE::~1BILi0EE()
-----------------------------
D::~D()
1BILi2EE::~1BILi2EE()
1BILi1EE::~1BILi1EE()
1BILi0EE::~1BILi0EE()
```

**Questions:**

**1)** Why are the names from each typeid so strange? Is there a way to calculate each one? I figured out that if I change my compiler the names change aswell.

**2)** Why is my program printing twice the output from my destructor from B base class. Is it related with virtual type and inheritance?

**3)** Can somebody explain me the benefits of using static_cast instead dynamic_cast? From every perspective I have been taught, static_cast usually have more problems in execution time vs dynamic_cast.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: **(1)** Those are decorated names of template instantiations, I suspect; the names under which the linker knows them. Note that [`type_info::name`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) is not required to produce any particular string: "Returns an implementation defined null-terminated character string containing the name of the type. No guarantees are given; in particular, the returned string can be identical for several types and change between invocations of the same program."

Comment: **(2)** I don't quite understand the question. Your program creates two instances of `D`. Each of those constructs three instances of various instantiations of `B`: a base class subobject, and two data members. Whenever an instance of `D` is destroyed, `~D` destructor runs as well as destructors of all three of those `B` instances. What goes up, must come down; what gets constructed, must get destroyed. What again do you find surprising?

Comment: **(3)** `dynamic_cast` needs to traverse, at run time, the data structures describing your class hierarchy (that's what makes it "dynamic"). `static_cast` is executed mostly at compile time; it has barely any effect on the generated machine code. I can't think of any situation where a `static_cast` would be slower than a `dynamic_cast`. You seem to suggest you've seen that: can you show an example? With all due respect, I find this claim difficult to believe.

Comment: Thank you a lot @IgorTandetnik. For the example in number **3)** (the example that my teacher used): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/c36yw7x9.aspx Specifically, the second box of code.

Comment: @xFunkyTImes: One question per question, please.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Answers in the comments section? :(

Comment: What exactly do you wish to demonstrate with this example?

Comment: `B<0>& b{*new D};` Why are you writing code like this?

Comment: Should I then copy+paste three times the same code in three different topics, only changing the questions? @BoundaryImposition

Comment: When you post a question, you post the relevant code that accompanies it. If the code happens to be the same for multiple questions, then so be it. But here you have broken the Q&A model by amalgamating three completely distinct questions into one post. Furthermore, two of the three questions have been well-covered before and would be closed as duplicates.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Two of these three contain requests for clarification. Those properly belong in comments, don't they? Comment for **(1)** is self-contained, but I'm not sure whether it's OK to write an answer that only responds to one third of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can somebody explain me the benefits of using `static_cast` instead `dynamic_cast`? From every perspective I have been taught, `static_cast` usually have more problems in execution time vs `dynamic_cast`.

The benefit of `static_cast` is that it is a less expensive operation but, yes, it has more problems.

Take the following simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct Foo
{
   virtual ~Foo () {}
};

struct Bar1 : Foo
{
   Bar1(int v) : v_(v) {}
   int v_;
};

struct Bar2 : Foo
{
   Bar2(double v) : v_(v) {}
   double v_;
};

void test_static_cast(Foo& f)
{
   std::cout << static_cast<Bar1&>(f).v_ << std::endl;
}

void test_dynamic_cast(Foo& f)
{
   std::cout << dynamic_cast<Bar1&>(f).v_ << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   Bar1 b(10);

   test_static_cast(b);
   test_dynamic_cast(b);
}
```

The output is same regardless of whether you use `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast`. However, if you change `main` to use `Bar2` instead of `Bar1`,

```
int main()
{
   Bar2 b(10);

   test_static_cast(b);
   test_dynamic_cast(b);
}
```

the `static_cast` version goes into the territory of undefined behavior while the `dynamic_cast` version throws a `std::bad_cast` exception. You can deal with the exception in a predictable manner while there is no predictable behavior of the `static_cast` version.

Use `static_cast` only if are **VERY CERTAIN** of what you are dealing with. Otherwise, opt for the more expensive but more reliable `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: Thank you a lot! This was mainly the answer I was searching for number **3)**. Basically, if I understand fine: -If you want less expensive operation but higher risk, you use static_cast. +If you want higher expensive operation but lower risk, you use dynamic_cast, because you can know exactly what's going on thanks to exceptions.

Comment: @xFunkyTImes, exactly.